# How to check if ECS is gracefully stopping my application in container

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

So, in my docker container, I have below entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entry_point.sh"]
CMD ["start"]
```

and in my `entry_point.sh`, I have below command running,

```
exec "${SDC_DIST}/bin/app" "$@"
```

Now, this whole docker is running in ECS/Fargate setup.
Also, in my docker container, another background process running is `cw-agent`, whose job is to send the application logs to CW.

and in my container setup I have provided `ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT` as 600.
So, as per my understanding, When ECS decides,  to stop a container it executes the equivalent of `docker stop <containerId>`. The service then has a certain amount of time to which is 600sec to comply before being faced with a `docker kill <containerId>`.So, initially, the service will receive a SIGTERM, and if it doesn’t comply it will then be hit with a SIGKILL. The time between the SIGTERM and the SIGKILL is configured `ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT`.

Since, my shell script in entrypoint uses `exec` so my startup `app` got the PID as 1 inside the container.
So, when the stopping signal received by running task, how can I make sure/check that my application gracefully shutdown? because in CW logs I still see some entries after SIGTERM and I really believe that my application never end-up gracefully?  Beware that CW-Log is a secondary application running.

So, I was thinking of introducing, catching the SIGKILL like this [Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/). That means when the container hit the SIGKILL command after 600sec, I would like to makesure if really application has been shut down if not wait? is it possible? or is there some other way I can achieve this? Because I don't know, what is the sweetstop of time between SIGKILL and SIGTERM.

Comment: The problem is probably that your application is executed by the entrypoint shell script.

Comment: The shell script is receiving the SIGTERM, but not your application.
I had the same problem with using the shell vs the exec form in my ENTRYPOINT command.

I replaced `ENTRYPOINT python3 app.py` with `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "app.py"]` which resulted in my SIGTERM handler getting triggered.
References:
https://medium.com/@dar3.st/graceful-termination-of-a-node-app-in-aws-ecs-29e8c596c47d